# Python- ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PCM'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing a voice detection project on Python3.10. However, I cannot run my code it said: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PCM" (line 7)  I tried to pip install PCM and pip install confusion-matrix again and again but it's still the same. I don't know how to fix it; hopefully, someone can help me. Thank you very much!

Here is my code

```
####### IMPORTS #############
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report
from PCM.PCM import plot_confusion_matrix
import pickle

##### Loading saved csv ##############
df = pd.read_pickle("final_audio_data_csv/audio_data.csv")

####### Making our data training-ready
X = df["feature"].values
X = np.concatenate(X, axis=0).reshape(len(X), 40)

y = np.array(df["class_label"].tolist())

####### train test split ############
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

##### Training ############

logit_reg = LogisticRegression(max_iter=10000)
logit_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
score = logit_reg.score(X_test, y_test)
print("Model Score: \n")
print(score)

#### Evaluating our model ###########
print("Model Classification Report: \n")

y_pred = logit_reg.predict(X_test)
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
plot_confusion_matrix(cm, classes=["Does not have WW", "Has WW"])

#### Save the model
pickle.dump(logit_reg, open('saved_model/WWD_ML.txt', 'wb'))

'''
To load the model again run this:

>>> model = pickle.load(open('saved_model/WWD_ML.txt', 'rb'))
>>> model.predict(<-- your matrix -->) # to predict
'''
```

here is my terminal

```
PS C:\Users\adamn\Documents\voice detection\WakeWordDetection-master\WakeWordDetection-master> & C:/Users/adamn/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe "c:/Users/adamn/Documents/voice detection/WakeWordDetection-master/WakeWordDetection-master/UsingML.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\adamn\Documents\voice detection\WakeWordDetection-master\WakeWordDetection-master\UsingML.py", line 7, in <module>        
    from PCM.PCM import plot_confusion_matrix
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PCM'
PS C:\Users\adamn\Documents\voice detection\WakeWordDetection-master\WakeWordDetection-master>
```

Comment: Hi @Tom, can you try to do a `pip list` and see if PCM is in there?
Also, can you try to do a `pip3 list` and see if it is there, if not try to do a `pip3 install PCM`

Comment: I tried, but nothing happened. The terminal cannot find PCM and it still error

Comment: Are you using VScode? if so, try changing the python version and then try launching the app.